# Adding jQuery code to Index.aspx pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<script runat="server">   
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("MyScript",
       "<script language=javascript>"+ 
       "alert(Date());"+ 
       "</script>");

    }

</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewBag.Message %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

This is giving me following error:

```
Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste from your old index page to your new (or copy and paste the script src reference).  This has nothing to do with ASP at all.

Comment: I cannot add these javascript code to Site.Master. This is page specific. When I am copying and pasting javascript code, it is saying invalid code.

Answer (score 0):

include jquery's link to your page(**before** your jquery-using code)...

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>`

If you use masterpage, add it in there, so all pages have it already included. Then after that, all you need is copy your code as-is.